# Cannot see other users' live cursor position in WOPI office online co-authoring

Tags: ms-wopi, office-online-server

We have a server running Office Online and a back-end on a separate server that works as the wopi host. The problem is, when this back-end is running on the same server as the office online, co-authoring works perfectly fine (multiple users can edit a document and also view other users' current cursor positions in the document) but when this back-end runs on a separate server, multiple users can edit a document at the same time but their live cursor position is not visible.

URL for the first scenario : `localhost/we/wordeditorframe.aspx?WOPISrc=http://localhost:8080/wopi/files/test.docx`

URL for the second scenario : `https://{office_online_domain}/we/wordeditorframe.aspx?WOPISrc=https://{wopihost_domain}/wopi/files/test.docx`

Any help is immensely appreciated!

Comment: If you compare the browser logs in the dev console, is there any difference when running WOPI on a separate server?

Comment: @rocky No it's the same in both scenarios